# Mux a regular file into Mpeg TS

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

im working in a file broadcasting method using mpeg2-ts and ISDB-T ( Integrated Services Digital Broadcasting - Terrestial), My problem is that  im not being able to to put a file into the data stream, or as rawvideo, or anithing inside the mpeg-ts.... im using ffmpeg and avconv. Here is an example of a test:

ffmpeg  -f mpegts -i Myfile.tgz -probesize FILESIZE  -mpegts_original_network_id 0x1 -mpegts_transport_stream_id 0x1 -mpegts_service_id 0x25 -mpegts_pmt_start_pid 0xbb9 -mpegts_start_pid 0xbba -metadata service_provider="FILESSERVER" -metadata service_name="FILES"   -muxrate 16M   output.ts

Comment: this is for sending pdf books to remote schools... please help.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to send the same file to multiple clients who might be on slow satellite links you can use UFTP which is multicast FTP over UDP. This can be more reliable than an MPEG-TS stream and will save you some headache. [See here](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: its not via satellite, its by air  tv broadcast signals in remote locations

Comment: This idea would benefit from [Forward Error Correction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170652/is-it-possible-to-add-error-correction-codes-bch-rs-or-etc-to-a-single-file). Losing a few bits in the PDF is much worse than losing a few frames in the video.

Answer (score 3):

You can interpret the file as a binary text.

```
ffmpeg -f bin -i Myfile.tgz -c copy
-mpegts_original_network_id 0x1 -mpegts_transport_stream_id 0x1 -mpegts_service_id 0x25
-mpegts_pmt_start_pid 0xbb9 -mpegts_start_pid 0xbba
-metadata service_provider="FILESSERVER" -metadata service_name="FILES"
-muxrate 16M output.ts
```

Then, to extract it

```
ffmpeg -i output.ts -c copy -map 0 -f data myfile.tgz
```

(You may get an I/O error message in the first command. But the result was fine.)