# Encoding a Data Stream Alongside Video in FFMPEG

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm wanting to encode some proprietary data (it's a serialised unsigned 64-bit integer per frame) into a video container (mp4) as a data stream, but I have been unable to find any instructions/tutorials of anyone doing this.

The only thing I've been able to find is this, which describes potentially how to create a data stream (the user had no success apparently
https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2006-November/005070.html)

This is my current code for creating a stream:

```
    ff_data_stream = avformat_new_stream(ff_output_context, NULL);

    ff_data_stream->codec->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA;
    ff_data_stream->codec->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_NONE;
    ff_data_stream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
```

But then when I'm calling `avformat_write_header` it errors with the following output to console:

> [mp4 @ 0x7fff68000900] track 1: could not find tag, codec not
>   currently supported in container

So my questions are as follows:

- Is it possible to create a data stream with an mp4 container? If not, are there any containers that do?

  - This might not be the right way to do this, but I have not yet come across any method of doing so.
- If so, how can I configure the stream correctly? (Whether it's for this container or another)
- Would one then use an AVPacket when writing to file? And write it into the file by using `av_interleaved_write_frame`?

Thanks

Comment: You can mux a data stream into a MPEG-TS file. See command-line [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38725773/5726027).

Comment: @AdmiralJonB I'm having a similar issue when trying to remux (not encode) a data stream, any tips if you ever found something?

Comment: @Maxito Sorry for the late reply, I only just saw it. Ultimately I ended up with doing what Gyan said and put it into a .ts file. Having trouble with it these days with an updated version of FFMPEG though.