# Streaming binary data with FFmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using FFmpeg in a C++ library to live stream video and audio. What I want is to stream some binary data as a separate stream.

If I'm reading correctly, Mp4 container supports "private streams" which can contain any kind of data. However I can't find out any info on how to add such a stream with FFmpeg. My idea is to have a stream of type **AV_MEDIA_TYPE_DATA** that uses codec **AV_CODEC_ID_BIN_DATA**.

What I want is very closely described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977561/encoding-a-data-stream-alongside-video-in-ffmpeg), but it wasn't answered.

Comment: mp4 might support private streams but ffmpeg's muxer does not. You can either add missing support to ffmpeg or hack around it by using one of supported formats (e.g. maybe you can add "video" stream with `AV_CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO` and `AV_PIX_FMT_MONOWHITE` and write your data as set of "pictures").

Comment: @AndreyTurkin I had investigated coding my information using a video codec. Unfortunately ffmpeg keeps complaining rtp doesn't support it. How do I go about adding missing support to FFmpeg? Just need a starting point, I'll investigate from there. Is "adding a new codec to ffmpeg" a good starting point? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a new codec, `AV_CODEC_ID_BIN_DATA` should be good enough. If you want to tackle mp4, see `avformat/rtpenc.c`; you'd need to make it understand this codec id and output proper mp4 "private stream" tags - that might or might not be enough. Not sure what rtp has to do with anything here though... Is there a chance you are not using mov container after all?

Comment: @AndreyTurkin I use rtsp://<ip>/live.sdp for streaming, and afaik that only supports mp4 as container right? Presently my video is H264 and audio is AAC. When I try to find a codec using `AV_CODEC_ID_BIN_DATA` it says no codec found (`avcodec_find_encoder` returns NULL)

Comment: IIUC rtsp uses rtp to send each stream individually; there is no container whatsoever (unless you count rtsp itself). So you need to make rtsp/rtp to accept your binary stream. There is a chance it would be as easy as adding codec id to `is_supported` function in `rtpenc.c`... or might not be. Oh, and regarding codec - there is no codec for binary data since there is nothing to encode. You just setup AVStream with this codec id, and fill raw data in AVPacket - no codec involved, same as with raw audio/video.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin that sounds like a good idea actually. From what I can see in rtpenc.c, if it gets a codec it doesn't know it'll just send the raw data anyway. Perhaps I can get away with merely sending raw AVPackets. This will take some time for me to test, but I'll post an answer here if it works out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @AndreyTurkin it did work. I succeeded in sending binary data after some modifications to rtp code in FFmpeg. The code is still in a very much raw state, I'll post it later once I clean it up. Thanks for your help :)